# Google Static Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I use the static map google webService in my iOS app.
And when i read the google document of the static map, i found this Note:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=fr#Limits

```
The Google Static Maps API has the following usage limits:

25 000 free static map requests per application per 24 hour period.
Additional image requests can be purchased on a per application basis at the rate currently listed in the FAQ. Additional quota is purchased through the API Console and requires the use of an API key.

If a user exceeds these limits, the server will return an HTTP 403 status.
```

Then i created an app that sent more then 25 000 request to the WebService,
but my application from the other devices and the iOS still working without any problem.
Please someone can explain to me, what the static map WebService work, because i reached the number max of the request/application and my ios App still work on the other devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an ip or from a device number of free request that can be made from google is 25000 request only per day after this you have to pay to google for it. So answer to your question is request from a particular ip is considered for calulating total requests.